# ComboBox if statement

Tags: c#

I've got a combobox with 3 values: File1, File2, and File3. I'm trying to change the value of textbox FileLocation depending on which value is chosen. With my code right now, the value is blank and doesn't change.

```
public string value1;
public string value2;
public string value3;

private void CooseFileOption()
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (CPABox.SelectedText == "File1")
    {
        value1 = ofd.FileName;
    }
    else if (CPABox.SelectedText == "File2")
    {
        value2 = ofd.FileName;
    }
    else if (CPABox.SelectedText == "File3")
    {
        value3 = ofd.FileName;
    }
}

private void CPABox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CPABox.DisplayMember == "File1")
    {
        FileLocation.Text = value1;
    }
    else if (CPABox.SelectedText == "File2")
    {
        FileLocation.Text = value2;
    }
    else if (CPABox.SelectedText == "File3")
    {
        FileLocation.Text = value3;
    }
}
```

CooseFileOption() is called when a button is pressed.

Comment: The code right now just sets a variable. Unless something else puts that data in the TextBox, it's not going to change. On the contrary, your second method does change the control.

Comment: the second method should happen whenever the option in the combobox is changed from each file, which should cause the value for FileLocation to change right?

Comment: You need to [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox). The `DisplayMember` property doesn't do what you think it does, neither does the `SelectedText` property. Also, the `SelectedIndexChanged` doesn't work as you seem to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that i was overthinking it,
instead of `CPABox.SelectedText` i could just use `CPABox.Text`